# Getting Video path from third party app (e.g. WhatsApp) to my app via content:// URI

Tags: android, share, filepath, intentfilter

I am trying to get video path from third party app (e.g WhatsApp) to my app (being tested on Marshmallow). When I share the video from WhatsApp and share it with my app, I get URI something like this:

content://com.whatsapp.provider.media/item/12

```
 // Get intent, action and MIME type
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    String type = intent.getType();
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {

         if ("text/plain".equals(type)) {

        } else if (type.startsWith("image/")) {

        } else if (type.startsWith("video/")) {

        Uri videoUri = (Uri) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
        }
```

}

How to get the path of video file from the above URI ?

Comment: I tried with this link, but i am unable to get the path, can someone help me with this.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51530890/how-to-share-a-video-from-whatsapp-to-my-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {

     if ("text/plain".equals(type)) {

    } else if (type.startsWith("image/")) {

    } else if (type.startsWith("video/")) {

       handleReceivedVideo(intent); // Handle video received from whatsapp URI
    }
```

}

In **handleReceivedVideo()** you need to open inputStream and then copy it into a file.

```
void handleReceivedVideo(Intent intent) throws IOException {
Uri videoUri = (Uri) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
if (videoUri != null) {
  File file = new File(getCacheDir(), "video.mp4");
  InputStream inputStream=getContentResolver().openInputStream(videoUri);
  try {

    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);
    try {
      byte[] buffer = new byte[4 * 1024]; // or other buffer size
      int read;

      while ((read = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, read);
      }

      output.flush();
    } finally {
      output.close();
    }
  } finally {
    inputStream.close();
    byte[] bytes =getFileFromPath(file);

  }
}
```

}

**getFileFromPath()** gets you the bytes which you can upload on your server.

```
public static byte[] getFileFromPath(File file) {
int size = (int) file.length();
byte[] bytes = new byte[size];
try {
  BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
  buf.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
  buf.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
}
return bytes;
```

}

Comment: Man, I can't believe there is no document or article talking about this!